# How to deal with multi-threading with evernote api on iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, evernote

I'm now developing an app on iOS with evernote api. and I have some problems about multi-threading. Below is the multi-threading mechanism in my app, is good or bad? any suggestion is  welcome.

1. Use MainThread(Thread a) to display and refresh UI.
2. Use Thread b to download noteList from evernote when user at noteList page.
3. Use Thread c to download noteResource from evernote when user at noteDetail page.

If user click on one note in noteList page when Thread b is not finished. should I cancel Thread b before use thread c to download noteResource? or is it safe to run both Thread b and Thread c at one time?

Any document or tuition about this available?

I have added code below, is right? When user first login, masterSync will run, note title will download and display. After this, if user press sync button, masterSync will run again, but now it crash at access authenticationToken of authResult when noteStore alloc/init, I saved the authResult when user login successful, is right?

```
-(void)sync:(id)obj {
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [AppDelegate sharedOperationQueue];

    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Note class]]) {
        self.detailSync = [[[EvernoteDetailSync alloc] initWithNote:obj] autorelease];
        detailSync.noteStore =[[[EvernoteNoteStore alloc] initWithToken:[authResult authenticationToken] shardId:[[authResult user] shardId]] autorelease];
        [operationQueue addOperation:detailSync];
    } else {
        self.masterSync = [[[EvernoteMasterSync alloc] initWithNotebookGuid:obj] autorelease];
        masterSync.noteStore =[[[EvernoteNoteStore alloc] initWithToken:[authResult authenticationToken] shardId:[[authResult user] shardId]] autorelease];
        [operationQueue addOperation:masterSync];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Evernote NoteStore class is not thread safe. To make multiple concurrent Evernote API requests, you can create multiple NoteStore objects.

Comment: should I relogIn every time before sync with multi-threading? if yes, should I relogIn in main thread or second thread?